# AFV Model Implementation for Convertible Bonds

Tags: options, option-pricing, american-options, black-scholes-pde, convertible-bond

I am reading the original AFV model paper for pricing convertible bonds.

https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~paforsyt/convert.pdf

The paper is very technical and I am having trouble finding the actual PDE's to solve. Can someone who is familiar with the paper give me a hand? He gives the PDE to solve using the notation: (x=0) or (y=0) or (z=0). I would like a practical example for implementation using the complementary PDE's.