# Convertible bonds pricer - implementation

Tags: fixed-income, programming, bond, reference-request, convertible-bond

Where I can find numerical implementation (in any programming language) of convertible bonds pricer based on the following article:

**E. Ayache, P. A. Forsyth, K. R. Vetzal, "The Valuation of Convertible Bonds With Credit Risk"**

For more details I refer also to this topic: [Link](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/41200/afv-model-implementation-for-convertible-bonds)

Comment: For what its worth the implementation requested would appear to be an application of the crank-nicholson discretisation method to the numerical method (A) described on page 23 within the conclusion section. Also possibly an extension to the supplementary method (A.2)

Comment: The model is old so I believe it has already been implemented in some pricing libraries (R, Python, C++, etc). Maybe somebody knows where i can find it. Thanks for your input.